# Piping yes and printf to pacat has different effect. (How to flush a pipe in bash?)

Tags: bash, pipe, pulseaudio

`yes aaaa | pacat` produces a sound. `{ while true; do printf "aaaa\n"; done } | pacat` however has no audible effect. When the latter is killed (ctrl+c) it produces a very brief sound however. Why? I suspect it might be that `yes` flushes the output every time it's executed. If that is the case, how can i manually flush the output?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Each of the two commands generates sound. As far as I can tell the sound is the same in both cases. Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS; kernel 4.15.0; `pacat` 11.1; libpulse 11.1.0; GNU `bash` 4.4.20.

Comment: I ran your two commands for five seconds, with `wc -l` on the outputs. `yes` produces about 1800 times as much output as a `while` loop. I'm not clear why 0x616161610A should be a sane 'raw audio stream' without any timing information, but I would guess a frequency change of eleven octaves might make a difference to the audible range of the output. A bat or a blue whale might hear something. Nevertheless, I get the same result as you (OP) do, on Linux Mint 19.3 with a USB soundbar. `man gcc | pacat` runs for six seconds and sounds like a steam train at high speed, blowing its whistle.

Comment: Same here, I can't reproduce it (coreutils 8.32, bash 5.1.4, libpulse 14.2 on Arch Linux). However, to address the difference between `yes` and the `while` loop: `strace`ing `yes` shows it groups writes (here, 8190 bytes at a time), `strace`ing the while loop shows it writes 5 bites at a time. `pacat` reads ~300 bytes (variable) at a time in the former case, ~64KiB at a time in the latter. Roughly the same sound in both cases.